# Children of Children of MovieClip not showing up when MovieClip is added to stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This problem seems very simple to me, but I've been unable to fix it, or find an answer anywhere.

This is in a class constructor for a class called `block`, `block_maker` is the object that called the constructor, an instance of `level`.

```
this.bitmap = new Bitmap(this.bitmap_data);

this.addChild(this.bitmap);     

this.block_maker.stage_foreground.addChild(this);
```

In `level`, `stage_foreground` is added to the stage, but nothing appears. `trace(stage_foreground.numChildren);` shows the correct count of children, and `var temp = (this.stage_foreground.getChildAt(0));   trace(temp.numChildren);` correctly but the children OF the children don't actually show up, the stage just stays blank.

When I change the above code to

```
this.bitmap = new Bitmap(this.bitmap_data);

this.block_maker.stage_foreground.addChild(this.bitmap);
```

the blocks appear on the stage, as children of `level_instance.stage_foreground`, but with this method, the bitmaps aren't appropriately positioned, as they have no position data. I can simply give `this.bitmap` `x` and `y` positions, and it works, but I am curious as to why it won't work when just adding the bitmap as a child to the block and then adding that as a child to `stage_foreground`.

I've tried replacing `this.bitmap` with a number of other object classes, such as a temporary `MovieClip` I made, or a `Shape`, but nothing shows up, so I know it has nothing to do with it being a `Bitmap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated

> This is in a class constructor for a class called block, block_maker
> is the object that called the constructor, an instance of level.

```
this.bitmap = new Bitmap(this.bitmap_data);
this.addChild(this.bitmap);     
this.block_maker.stage_foreground.addChild(this);
```

The level class needs to to extend a display object for it to show up.
In other words

> "this"

has to be a display object or extend it in some form.

The reason this doesn't work.

```
this.block_maker.stage_foreground.addChild(this);
```

and this does

```
this.block_maker.stage_foreground.addChild(this.bitmap);
```

Is because "this" is not a display object but "this.bitmap" is.

[The DisplayObject class is the base class for all objects that can be placed on the display list.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, even though it's not neccesary, I'd suggest to make a classname start with a capital letter, and vars always start with a lower-case letter. It's a common 'rule' in AS3 that's mainly to avoid confusion.

The problem most likely lies within you use of `this`; what you're doing is adding `this` *into* `this`. It seems to me it's not a proper way of coding.

Also, since all of the other attempts didn't work; have you tried to make the var you want ot add a `public static` var?

Comment: But this.block_maker is simply stores a reference to a different object, so this.block_maker is actually a reference to an external object, and thus, if I understand correctly, I am not adding `this` into `this`. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: I'm not sure either, but as far as my knowledge reaches, `this` always refers to the class the `this` instance is written in. Again, I'm not entirely sure so maybe I should freshen up my AS3 skills a bit :p

Comment: Well you are right, but in `this.something` the "something" can be more or less anything, including an instance of another class, which in this case it is.